# How to write a modularized copy subroutine for cells in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to be able to write a copy subroutine that will read in the input worksheet name and the input cells, and copy this data to a specific output sheet and output cells. This subroutine must be modularized because it will be used in mulitiple worksheets.It will only copy the data from input sheets to output sheets. Here is one I have written but it doesn't work.

```
Public Sub Copy_Input_Data_To_Output_Data( _
 ByVal pv_str_input_worksheet_name As String, _
 ByVal pv_str_output_worksheet_name As String, _
 ByVal pv_str_input_cell_range As String, _
 ByVal pv_str_output_cell_range As String, _
 ByRef pr_str_error_message As String)

 Worksheets(pv_str_input_worksheet_name).Range(pv_str_input_cell_range).Value  = _
 Worksheets(pv_str_output_worksheet_name).Range(pv_str_output_cell_range).Value
End Sub
```

Here is the code of that subroutine being applied to a input sheet.

```
Call Copy_Input_Data_To_Output_Data( _
 pv_str_in… _
 pv_str_output_worksheet_name:="Sheet2", _
 pv_str_input_cell_range:="B13:B17", _
 pv_str_output_cell_range:=""B17,B20,B34,B18,B21", _
 pr_str_error_message:=str_error_message)
```

As you can see this code is copying ranges of input cells and the data goes to specific output cells in another sheet. Please help I would greatly appericate it! :)

Comment: `it doesn't work` - what doesn't work? Any error messages? And what do you mean by `modularized`? You need to be more specific.

Comment: reformatted you code, but you should correct the `Call` routine, because it has errors / missing data.

Comment: The code at the top is in a module in VBA. That code is suppose to be applied to multiple input and output sheets. What its suppose do is read in the input worksheet name and the cells that needs to copied. It then takes those values and checks what the output sheet name is. After finding the output sheet's name, it places the values in the cells for output sheet. The issue is transfering the data from input to output is a challenge. I can't seem to get it to copy the values over. The call code below is showing an example of the code being called in a input sheet. It doesn't work sadly :(

Comment: Thank you Jook! :) do you perhaps have an idea on how to get this to work propertly? The main error I get is the subscript going out of range error when I test the code.

Comment: maybe it's this simple, maybe not, but I see an extra `"` in this section of your Call statement `""B17,B20,B34,B18,B21",` ... that will throw the error you are getting for sure!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out. It will work pasting a contiguous range to / from a non-contiguous range and vice versa. You could probably enhance it to even be smart enough to detect if it's two same-sized contiguous ranges, so it wouldn't loop unnecessarily.

I've also reworded the code to simplify readability.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunIt()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet, yourSheet As Sheet1
Dim myRange As Range, yourRange As Range

Set mySheet = Sheets("mySheet")
Set yourSheet = Sheets("yourSheet")
Set myRange = mySheet.Range("A1:A3")
Set yourRange = yourSheet.Range("A6,B7,C8")

CopyCells mySheet, yourSheet, myRange, yourRange

End Sub

Sub CopyCells(wksIn As Worksheet, wksOut As Worksheet, rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range)

If rngIn.Cells.Count <> rngOut.Cells.Count Then

    MsgBox "Ranges are not equal. Please try again."
    Exit Sub

End If


Dim cel As Range, i As Integer, arrOut() As String
arrOut() = Split(rngOut.Address, ",")

i = 0

For Each cel In wksIn.Range(rngIn.Address)

    wksOut.Range(arrOut(i)).Value = cel.Value

    i = i + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I check for names of the worksheets instead of index?

Comment: @user1750089 -> can you either be more specific in question, or post your question, since it seems to be different, in another thread? That way all can benefit from it, instead of it being buried in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `Copy` method of the `Range` object. Something like the following, provided your ranges are OK - they are copied to `Range` objects for readability:

```
Dim oRangeIn as Range
Dim oRangeOut as Range

Set oRangeIn = Worksheets(pv_str_input_worksheet_name).Range(pv_str_input_cell_range)
Set oRangeOut = Worksheets(pv_str_output_worksheet_name).Range(pv_str_output_cell_range)

oRangeIn.Copy oRangeOut

Set oRangeIn = Nothing
Set oRangeOut = Nothing
```

If you change the statement calling the sub it will work - but maybe not as intended:

```
Call Copy_Input_Data_To_Output_Data( _
    "Sheet1", _
    "Sheet2", _
    "B13:B17", _
    "B17,B20,B34,B18,B21", _
    "")
```

Comment: The only thing is would this work for task I have? I am copying ranges of cells and outputting them to specific cells. An example would be like B13:17 for input then copying that to B17,B23,B38,B34

Comment: It will copy your range to all cells in your list, some of which will be overwritten by the same copy operation.

Comment: Do I need to add an .Value to the end of those Set statements?

Comment: In the output, I did fix it but the main error is subscript out of range. It seems copying a cell range to specific cells can't be done

Comment: I don't get an error when I run it. The `Range.Copy` method in my answer could do the copy you want, but you would have to call it once each for B13->B17, B14->B20 etc.